# How to split text by a specified quantity and newline character?

Tags: python, string

I want to divide the text into groups of every 1000 characters. If the end of a group is not a line break, it should be pushed forward or backward until the next line break is found before continuing the splitting.

I have tried, but I don't know how to implement it.

```
Content = open(text, "r", encoding="utf-8").read()
for i in range(0, len(Content), 1000):
    chunk = srtContent[i:i+1000]
    if not chunk.endswith('\n'):
```

Comment: So a group can contain more than one line break?

Comment: Well, it should be pushed forward or backward?

Comment: Yes, a group can contain multiple line breaks, and I hope that if a group of text reaches 1000 characters and is not ended by a line break, it can be delayed for splitting when there are more than 1000 characters, or split earlier when there are less than 1000 characters.

Comment: Actually, the purpose of the program is to split subtitle files, translate the segments and then reassemble them.